# Offset Function only works horizontally

Tags: excel, offset, lookup

I am able to pull a specific cell every 7th column with my OFFSET function, but it only pulls the correct number when I drag right, I need to drag out the formula down, thus filling my column with the correct information. Please help!

This is the formula I am currently using

```
=OFFSET(Shift!$AFV$14,0,(COLUMN(Shift!A1)*7))
```

Comment: Post the formula you're using ... we're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's breakdown your formula:

```
=OFFSET(Shift!$AFV$14,0,(COLUMN(Shift!A1)*7))
```

OFFSET is using this cell as the base:

```
Shift!$AFV$14
```

Because you used $ notation, it will ALWAYS reference that cell, regardless of where you copy this formula.

```
0
```

The next parameter, 0, says you want to work 0 rows offset. So the same row as $AFV$14 is on (ie row 14).

```
(COLUMN(Shift!A1)*7)
```

The final parameter you are telling it how many columns to offset.
You are using COLUMN function to pull the column NUMBER of the passed cell (in this case: `Shift!A1`
Because you did NOT use the $ notation, this cell reference WILL CHANGE when you copy the cell around.
So if you copy the cell to the right, it will read:

```
Shift!B1
```

if you copy it down, it will read:

```
Shift!A2
```

.. etc.

I'm not really sure why you are doing it this way, nor am I sure what you are trying to accomplish in the first place - so it's hard for me to correct the formula.

Hopefully with this explanation you can understand why it's only shifting to the right/left ... "because you told it to".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I am still learning this function. However, when I copy the cell to the right it reads Shift!B1 (not Shift!A2). I need it to do as stated in your explanation, I need it to read Shift!B1 when I copy down. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: My intent is to pull a specific statistic for every day of the month. There are multiple stats under each day, maybe I need to rearrange my data and use a lookup/match function. I'll keep playing with it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Heidi:  yeah, sorry, B1, not A2 ... :) getting my left/right up/down mixed up.  You may need some value in place of the "0" parameter.  Since you need it to shift down in some scenario ... Post some sample data and what you expect/need .. and we can help easier.